# Pandas: Grouping columns based on current index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, whose data i want to group into column groups

their current column index contains the name of the group i want to group by, and i'm having a problem with extracting only that part of the name.

the name of the columns is always "day_replicate". so i'm trying define a function that groups the columns into only days.

what im trying to do:

```
index |d0_1 | d0_2 | d1_1 | d1_2 |
data  |-----|------|------|------|
```

add a new line based on these indexes

```
index |d0_1 | d0_2 | d1_1 | d1_2 |
day   |d0   | d0   | d1   | d1   |
data  |-----|------|------|------|
```

group based on df[day]

```
def group(a: pd.DataFrame):
    def get_day(b: pd.DataFrame):
        list = []
        for i in b.columns:
            (d, r) = i.split("_")
            list.append(d)
        return list

    a["day"] = [get_day(a)]
    a.groupby(["day"] , axis=1)
    return a
```

im absolutely sure there is a lot better ways to do this, like with using a lambda function and list comprehension and stuff.
I wanted to get this to work first before i try condensing it. Id really appreciate any help!

Im also sure theres more errors in my code than what the error message is saying:

```
...
  File "C\...\vsstudio\msdatatry1.py", line 54, in group  
    a["day"] = [get_day(a)]
  File "C:\Users\sepps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3977, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\sepps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4171, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(value)
  File "C:\Users\sepps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4904, in _sanitize_column
    com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
  File "C:\Users\sepps\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 561, in require_length_match
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (8709)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    df.columns,
    df.columns.str.extract('_(\d+)', expand=False)
], names=['index', 'day'])

df.columns = new_idx
```

Before:

```
  d0_1 d0_2 d1_1 d1_2
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

After:

```
index d0_1 d0_2 d1_1 d1_2
day      1    2    1    2
0      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```